# Acquire SharePoint Document Library Level Security Users PowerShell

Tags: web-services, powershell, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint [Web Services Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to gather site level security users.  SharePoint recognizes Active Directory Security Groups as users (not as groups).  I gathered these pseudo-groups with a SOAP request (see below) utilizing SharePoint Web Services via `http://{site}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`:

```
$uri = $context
$soap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
$soap+= '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
$soap+= '<soap:Body>'
$soap+= '<GetUserCollectionFromWeb xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/" />'
$soap+= '</soap:Body>'
$soap+= '</soap:Envelope>'
[xml]$WF = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Credential $CRED -Method POST -ContentType "text/xml" -Body $soap

$Users = $WF.Envelope.Body.GetUserCollectionFromWebResponse.GetUserCollectionFromWebResult.GetUserCollectionFromWeb.Users.User
```

The above request is successful at the site and subsite level.  But is not successful at the library, lists and documents level.

Is there a resource via [Web Services Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that mirrors **GetUserCollectionFromWeb** at the Library, List and Document level?

I'm beginning to rip my hair out trying to access this data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the **Permissions** web service, accessible at `/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx`.

You can refer to MSDN documentation on the Permissions service [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions(v=office.12).aspx).

The [`GetPermissionCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions.permissions.getpermissioncollection(v=office.12).aspx) method will give you an xml fragment with members (by ID number) and permission masks.

You can use the [**People** web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/people(v=office.12).aspx)  (`/_vti_bin/People.asmx`) to associate member ID numbers with actual people and groups.